# Dropdown menu error [CSS, HTML, Javascript]

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I've been fiddling around with the dropdown menu code for a while. The resources here haven't helped me so far If you happen to find a relevant link, please share here :) 
My main issue is that the dropdown menu doesn't show.
Really appreciate your help.

Here's the relevant script :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is  my styles

```
    ul.topnav {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    ul.topnav li {
      float: left;
    }
    ul.topnav li a {
      display: block;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

    .topnav {
      position: relative;
    }
    ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {
      background-color: grey;
    }
    ul.topnav li a.active {
      background-color: #2a8d7b;
    }
    ul.topnav li.right {
      float: right;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      ul.topnav li.right,
      ul.topnav li {
        float: none;
      }
    }
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    /* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

    .dropbtn:focus {
      background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    /* Links inside the dropdown */

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div>
  <ul class="topnav">
    <li>
      <a onclick="myFunction()" href="#" class=dropbtn ">Filter</a>
    </li>
      <div id="myDropdown " class="dropdown-content ">
           <a href="# ">Link 1</a>
           <a href="# ">Link 2</a>
             <a href="# ">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    <li><a href="#news ">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact ">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="right "><a href="#about ">Impressum</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This Code is Taken from http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown

Comment: Your first `<a>` has an unclosed class attribute (missing `"`), and after that, all your attributes have a trailing space. Next you need to actually implement the `.show` rule you're adding. ... w3schools...? Oh my. Don't use that.

Comment: Thank you Chris. Are there websites you recommend?